# A way to check if any element of class is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to check if any of the elements of a class have been clicked with jQuery? I want to detect if an element with a certain class has been clicked.

Comment: You mean like... a click event handler? Or are you wondering if there's a log that can be searched of all events that happened on all elements?

Comment: ...looking at your previous questions, you've already assigned event handlers before, so what are you *actually* asking? And *what have you tried*?

Comment: Sorry for the weird question. What I wanted to ask is how to check if an element of a class has been clicked. I have 5 div elements with the same class. And if any of them is clicked I want a function to return false.

Comment: You need to assign an event handler like normal, and write some code in the handler to track whether it was clicked.

Comment: ...in your handler, just do `this.was_clicked = true` to assign a property directly to the element. This is the quickest/lightest way to do it. Don't use a heavy system like `.data()`. It's major overkill.

Comment: ...or if you just want the element to be clicked once, remove the handler after the first click.

Comment: I want it to be clicked as many times as the user wants to. And I need it for more elements not just one, that's my problem.

Comment: Then just doing `this.was_clicked` is still the quickest way. That property will stay with the element, and so it can be checked at any time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to detect if an element with a certain class has been clicked.

Well you could always subscribe to the [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event handler which will be invoked when a DOM element is being clicked upon:

```
$('.someClass').click(function() {
    // here you could use "this" to get the DOM element that was clicked.
});
```

you could then associate some metadata information with this DOM element if you want to track it using the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function:

```
$('.someClass').click(function() {
    var isClicked = $(this).data('clicked');
    if (!isClicked) {
        // it's the first time we are clicking on this element
        $(this).data('clicked', true);
    } else {
        // the user has already clicked on this element
    }
});
```

Comment: What about in pure JS?

Comment: What about pure JS?